# Check if app is running from startup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shortcut-file

I have made an application in python named `Swaminarayan.exe`. I wanted my program to start when my PC boots. So I created a shortcut named `Swaminarayan.lnk` and added it to:

`C:\Users\<Current User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`

But my application behaves differently when the app is in *AUTO_START* and when Not in *AUTO_START*. How can I detect if my app is running from shortcut or not.

Can I do something like this?

```py
if AUTO_START:
    // do this
else:
    // do that
```

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a command line parameter to the startup shortcut (in its Properties box), e.g. `--startup`.

Then you can use e.g.

```
import sys
# ...
is_startup = ('--startup' in sys.argv)
```

or if your program grows and you end up using e.g. `argparse`:

```
import argparse
# ...
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('--startup', action='store_true', default=False)
args = ap.parse_args()
if args.startup: ...
```

Comment: I am unable to understand how to implement this. The application I have made is made in **tkinter**, I cannot access the command line.

Comment: Yes, of course you can access the command line. Even if the application doesn't have a command window, the process is still passed arguments. E.g. [this screenshot](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wh-74astV5Y/UgusYVmWjXI/AAAAAAAAAlY/VwEgUQzznUs/s1600/TechiMen-in-Internet-Explorer.png) shows how to pass an argument.

Comment: https://github.com/ajinzrathod/share/blob/main/startup.py This is my code. How should I write code in this one?.

Comment: I mean startup is controlled by windows right. So how can I add arguments on my own?

Comment: See the screenshot. Open the Properties for the shortcut you've placed in your Startup folder, then just add ` --startup` or anything else you like after the .exe name. The shortcuts are launched more or less like you'd double-clicked it.

Comment: If you don't believe me, you can replace `var.set("Swaminarayan")` in your code with `var.set(" ".join(sys.argv))` and fiddle with the Properties :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233233/discussion-between-ajinzrathod-and-akx).